# WIX Feature Tree de-selecting sub-features doesn't change size of parent component

Tags: wix, wix3.5

Under my parent component are three sub-components - a website and two window services. A hidden sub-feature also has the database scripts that are executed using SQLCMD.

When I deselect any of the sub-features, it doesn't change size of parent component i.e. the size of the parent component doesn't decrease, it remains the same as when all the features are selected.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The terminology here is confusing. Are "sub-components" in your lingo Features? If so, then how big are the File elements in the Features? The cost will only include the size of Files unless you add costs with the ReserveCost element.